# Loop for handler in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call a particular service after 1 minute and it is in a loop?
So I tried the below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++)
{
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Log.e("value", "coming up");
            openTransaction();
        }
   }, startTransaction);
}
```

int temp has 4 and Strangely I can see 4 logs immediately instead of logging every 1 minute.. Can somebody help me to open the required method only after 1 minute which is in a loop?

I am not sure where I am wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: what's the value of startTransaction?

Comment: @Blackbelt, startTransaction should be time in milliseconds, but not specified in question

Comment: in that case you must need to use Thread() along with the sleep() method, instead of a Handler..

Comment: @Blackbelt: i think problem is not `startTransaction `. behavior is due to `for-loop`, which adding `temp ` messages in `queue` with same time `startTransaction `

Comment: startTranscation is in milliseconds 60000

Comment: this sentence *Temp value has 4 and Strangely I can see 4 logs immediately instead of waiting for 1 minute* is poorly worded. What you mean by *instead of waiting for 1 minute*?

Comment: @Blackbelt : I have rephrased the sentence.. Hope you can understand now.

Comment: @MaheshB: can you guide me with it? I mean an example or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it may help..

```
Thread mThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // code to call your service
                            openTransaction();
                        }
                    });
                    sleep(60000); // one minute
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            super.run();
        }
    };
    mThread.start();
```